# How to map XML data structure to database with JPA (Java EE)

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm on a project, where I get XML data like invoices from a service provider. These invoices have many positions with the same structure, like Adress, Service Type, and amount of costs. I need to store this data in seperate datasets in different rows. I got an XML schema file from my provider.

I could unmarshall the XML files to java Objects. Is there a way to insert this data to a database with JPA. the problem is, that the through JAXB generated classes doesn't have annotations like Entity or columns. I could annotate these classes but after a "clean and build" with Netbeans the classes will be generated again without annotations.

Anyone know a way to build classes from XML schema with JAXB, read the incoming XML files, unmarshal this? and write the data to database.

Comment: You could do the JPA mapping in XML, like in the olden times before annotations. You'll need to check with your JPA implementation on how to do this.

Comment: You may be interested in HyperJAXB which will generate a java model from an XML schema that contains both JAXB and JPA annotations:  http://java.net/projects/hyperjaxb

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Java Bean to Java Bean mapper like [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) to map your generated classes to JPA entities.